# How to record a screen with internal audio in a flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I tried using the flutter_screen_recording plugin but it can not record internal audio.

This is the plugin:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording

Does anyone know a way to record both the phone’s screen and the phone’s internal audio (ie, sounds coming from the phone’s speaker) in Flutter?

Comment: were you able to record the device's internal audio. If yes then please share your solution here.